# Software export compliance for App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have developed a game for iOS platform. This game uses **Google Analytics**.

I have following questions:

- Is my game(software) subject to export compliance for App Store submission?
- Do I need to provide any documents related to export compliance for App Store submission?

I would appreciate any suggestion and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Google Analytics contacts Google's servers over SSL. It is an encrypted connection.

Therefore yes, your app is subject to export compliance for App Store submission.

Usually you do not have to provide any documents to Apple for App Store submission. You just have to answer a simple questionnaire on the web site, which you're automatically asked.

You might also have to file a self-classification report annually to relevant US authorities, but this doesn't have anything to do with Apple. Instructions on doing that can be found here:

[How to file an Annual Self Classification Report](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/product-guidance/high-performance-computers/223-new-encryption/1238-how-to-file-an-annual-self-classification-report)

Comment: No problem! If this answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you please suggest any links which can provide information on how to file a self-classification report? Sorry, maybe I asking for too much of help.

Comment: It has been added now.